# parse xml google calendar event

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to parse google calendar events from this url: http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/amchamlva%40gmail.com/public/full
and here is my code:

```
 static IEnumerable<Event> getEntryQuery(XDocument xdoc)
    {
        return from entry in xdoc.Root.Elements().Where(i => i.Name.LocalName == "entry")
               select new Event
               {
                   EventId = entry.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "id").Value,
                   Published = DateTime.Parse(entry.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "published").Value),
                   Title = entry.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "title").Value,
                   Content = entry.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "content").Value,
                   Where = entry.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "gd:where").FirstAttribute.Value,
                   Link = entry.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "link").Attribute("href").Value,

               };
    }

using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(e.Result))
            {
                var results = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(results);

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(doc);

                var myFeed = getEntryQuery(doc);
                foreach (var feed in myFeed)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(feed.Content);

                }

            }
```

and It works almost fine, except for this:

```
Where = entry.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "gd:where").FirstAttribute.Value,
```

I got an exception probably because value it's null, actually i need to get valueString attribue value (for example 'Somewhere' in this case)

```
<gd:where valueString='Somewhere'/>
```

Answer (score 2):

'gd' looks like a namespace, take a look at how to work with xml namespaces in LINQ to XML:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387093.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669152.aspx

Maybe try something along the lines of

```
XNamespace gdns = "some namespace here";
entry.Elements(gdns + "where")
```

Answer (score 2):

The *local* name of `<gd:where>` is just `where` - the `gd` part is the namespace alias.

Rather than using all of these `First` calls checking the local name, it would be *much* cleaner if you'd just use the right fully qualified name. For example:

```
XNamespace gd = "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005";
XNamespace atom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

return from entry in xdoc.Root.Elements(gd + "entry")
       select new Event
       {
           EventId = (string) entry.Element(atom + "id"),
           Published = (DateTime) entry.Element(atom + "published"),
           Title = (string) entry.Element(atom + "title"),
           Content = (string) entry.Element(atom + "content"),
           Where = (string) entry.Element(gd + "where")
           Link = (string) entry.Element(atom + "link")
       };
```

(That's making educated guesses on the namespace based on some [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_protocol). You should check this against your actual feed though.)

Answer (score 2):

thanks for your help guys, it works with this simple code:

```
   //Where = entry.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "where").Value,
   Where = entry.Elements().First(i => i.Name.LocalName == "where").Attribute("valueString").Value,
```

later I'll try to implement your suggestions for a better code implementation ;)